# Indices - factorising

Tags: factoring

Simplify: $$\frac {x^5y^2x^3 + x^4y^5 - y^5x^7y^4}{x^4y^3}$$

I know this is probably low level stuff but I need to be able to do this specific type of question and I have no way of checking my work. If anyone could offer a step by step working I'd be appreciative

Comment: Well, if you want us to check your work you should provide it.  What answer do you get?

Comment: Note:  an excellent way of checking supposed simplifications is to plug in values.  If an algebraic identity is intended to hold for all $x,y$ then it must hold for particular $x,y$.  Try $(x,y)=(1,1), (2,1),(1,2)$ for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have
\begin{align*}
\frac {x^5y^2x^3 + x^4y^5 - y^5x^7y^4}{x^4y^3}
&=\frac {x^8y^2 + x^4y^5 - x^7y^9}{x^4y^3} \\
&=\frac {x^4y^2\big(x^4 + y^3 - x^3y^7\big)}{x^4y^3} \\
&=\frac {x^4 + y^3 - x^3y^7}{y},\quad x\not=0.
\end{align*}
That's about as far as you can go.

Comment: you should edit to show y is not zero (as it is what is in the denominator.

Comment: Don't need to. $y$ is still in the denominator. It's when a factor *disappears* from the denominator that you need to specify such a thing.

Comment: I sit corrected, then.

Answer (score 2):

The highest common factor of the terms in the numerator is $x^4y^2.$ This is also a factor of the denominator, hence you can cancel it off to get $$\frac{x^4+y^3-x^3y^7}{y}.$$

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way is to break the problem down into simple workable parts:
$$\frac{x^5y^2x^3+x^4y^5−y^5x^7y^4}{x^4y^3}$$
$$=\frac{x^5y^2x^3}{x^4y^3}+\frac{x^4y^5}{x^4y^3}-\frac{y^5x^7y^4}{x^4y^3}$$
$$=\frac{x^8y^2}{x^4y^3}+\frac{x^4y^5}{x^4y^3}-\frac{x^7y^9}{x^4y^3}$$
$$=\frac{x^4}{y}+y^2-x^3y^6,\quad x\not=0.$$
This is equivalent to the answers given above.

Comment: Technically, you'd need to add provisos like $x\not=0$ and maybe $y\not=0$ to be equivalent to my answer. When factors disappear from the denominator, it aids in clarity to display such a proviso.

Comment: Done -- thanks.